# Error in following google cloud workflow tutorial using nodejs 10 runtime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to follow https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/workflow-function, I have edited the workflow template a bit, but the issue I'm getting is at google cloud function. The tutorial asks to choose runtime as nodejs8, when I do that I get error as

```
Error: Node.js v10.0.0 is a minimum requirement. To learn about legacy version support visit: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node#supported-nodejs-versions
```

When I change the runtime to nodejs10 I get error at cloud function as

```
TypeError: client.workflowTemplatePath is not a function
                                                                   at exports.startWorkflow (/workspace/index.js:18:16)
                                                                   at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28)
                                                                   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Please help me to get this function running, either through nodejs8 or nodejs10

Thanks!

EDIT: As per the comments, turns out it's an api specific issue, can someone good with nodejs skills help me rewrite the instructions provided in the tutorial?

Comment: The tutorial is definitely out of date if it's using node 8.  As of June 5, node 8 is deprecated, and you should instead use node 10.  As for that error, I don't know, but you not use node 8 any more.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try to debug for nodejs10 then

Comment: The TypeError message that you are observing occurs usually when there was an attempt to call a value from a function, but the value is not actually a function [1]. So the issue is not likely related to Cloud Functions related rather Node JS specific and probably coming from this section " name: client.workflowTemplatePath(projectId, region, workflowTemplate)" of the Cloud Functions code snippet [2]. Please use NodeJS 10 runtime only. As Node JS 8 Runtime is depricated I requested to update this tutorial to Dataproc Engineering team. 
[1] https://rb.gy/nothep [2] https://rb.gy/atnanr

Comment: Thanks for the input, if I go to the api doc, the method is not there.
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dataproc.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Dataproc.V1.WorkflowTemplateServiceClient.html#methods
what is the alternative way to make the request then?
Also does it affect my old cloud functions that were deployed with nodejs8, what happens when I redeploy them?

Comment: Cloud Dataflow Engineering is looking into the issue to do necessary modification of the document. 
[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/workflow-function